# macOS: retrieve keychain's item's password and username with `security find-internet-password`

Tags: macos, shell, keychain

I would like to retrieve my appstoreconnect.apple.com username and password from macOS Keychain, to write a script with those credentials afterwards.
When I type `security find-internet-password -s "appstoreconnect.apple.com" -g` i get

```
keychain: "/Users/me/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
version: 512
class: "inet"
attributes:
    0x00000007 <blob>="appstoreconnect.apple.com"
    0x00000008 <blob>=<NULL>
    "acct"<blob>="my-username"
    "atyp"<blob>="dflt"
    "cdat"<timedate>=0x32303230303731363133343131315A00  "20200716134111Z\000"
    "crtr"<uint32>=<NULL>
    "cusi"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "desc"<blob>=<NULL>
    "icmt"<blob>=<NULL>
    "invi"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "mdat"<timedate>=0x32303230303731363133343533395A00  "20200716134539Z\000"
    "nega"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "path"<blob>="/"
    "port"<uint32>=0x00000000
    "prot"<blob>=<NULL>
    "ptcl"<uint32>="htps"
    "scrp"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "sdmn"<blob>=<NULL>
    "srvr"<blob>="appstoreconnect.apple.com"
    "type"<uint32>=<NULL>
password: "my-password"
```

how, from that, can I retrieve `my-username` and `my-password` values, to use as variables in my shell script ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
security find-internet-password -s 'appstoreconnect.apple.com' -g 2>&1 | grep -E 'acct|password' |  sed 's/^ *//' | sort | rev  | cut -d'"' -f2 | rev
```

An important thing to note is the `security` CLI returns the account name on stdout, but the password on stderr.  By adding `2>&1`, all stderr output will be redirected to stdout.  Then both outputs will be passed along to the next command in the pipeline.

I removed the leading spaces in case it affects the sorting.  The sorting makes the account name appear before the password.

I'm not totally satisfied with the output processing here.  Using `rev` a couple of times and treating quotes as delimiters feels kludgy.  This is good enough for the moment, I guess.  (Because it meets my immediate needs. )  I will update this later.

It'd be so helpful if macOS would print the account name and password without requiring all this trickery.

Comment: `security find-internet-password` accepts option `-w` to `Display only the password on stdout`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
security find-internet-password -s "appstoreconnect.apple.com" -g | grep -E "acct|password" |  rev  | cut -d'"' -f2 |  rev
```

Comment: Not so far: this return ```password: "my-password" \
my-username```
How can I set each in `$USERNAME` and `$PASSWORD` ?